# Implementing android animation like gmail inbox

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm writing an android app using romannurik`s Android-SwipeToDismiss using google cardview items. Swiping the cards is enabled in the app using the above romannuriks library.

Currently my problem is in implementing, another view come in background while i'm swiping the card, just like the implementation in gmail where I can see archive and undo while I'm swiping the card.

Any ideas would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This library could help you achive such effect or something similar
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

or you can do it by using swipe listview https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview